# Transforming Horizontal Table to Vertical Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could anyone give advice as whether this is possible in postgresql.

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT a.count as "A", b.count as "B" FROM
(SELECT count(*) FROM a) as a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b) as b;
```

This gives me a result like the following:

```
A    |    B
-----------
100  |  300
```

Is it possible to transform this to be displayed like:

```
Type   |   Count
----------------
A      |   100
B      |   300
```

Any advice would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`UNION`/`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) keyword:

```
SELECT 'A', count(*) 
FROM a
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', COUNT(*) 
FROM b;
```

Comment: YES! Works. Exellent!